# Installing multiple versions of MySQL on Oracle Linux

Tags: rhel, mysql, oracle-linux

I have a Oracle Linux 5 server. I have to install MySQL 5.1 as well as MySQL 5.6. Is it possible to install both version of MySQL on the same machine? If yes, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The program that can accomplish this is called [update-alternatives](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives)

You should be able to do something like this (untested)

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/mysql-server mysql-server /usr/bin/mysql-5-1/bin/mysql-server 10
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/mysql-server mysql-server /usr/bin/mysql-5-6/bin/mysql-server 10
```

- --install adds a new mapping
- /usr/bin/mysql-server is the link location (where mysql-server normally is located)
- mysql-server is the name of the mapping
- /usr/bin/mysql-5-6/bin/mysql-servera is where I placed the new version of mysql-server
- 10 is the priority

You then choose which version of mysql-server you want like so

```
update-alternatives --set mysql-server /usr/bin/mysql-5-6/bin/mysql-server
```

The way this works is by creating a symbolic link from /usr/bin/mysql-server and pointing it to the new path. ( /usr/bin/mysql-5-1/bin/mysql-server)